# MySQL Decimal 9.99999999

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the currency from google finance using a script and then I am writing the data into a database.

However when I do, I get `9.99999999` instead of what I sent over. I have my InnoDB set to DECIMAL (9,8).

```
 $conn->set_charset('utf8');            

 $add_currency_query = "INSERT INTO `currency_table`
 (`currency_rate`, `time_fetched`, `service`)
 VALUES ('$converted_amount', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 'google-finance')";
```

And my PHP

```
$get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
$get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
$converted_amount = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', null, $get[0]);
```

---

Any tips on how to fix this/am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECIMAL (9,8) means you have 9 symbols in total, 8 of those are after the dot. This means you can store only numbers up to 9.99999999 if you save anything above it it probably saves as 9.99999999

Suggestion: change your field to be something like DECIMAL (20,8)

Comment: Its weird cause the number I'm entering is, 61.5715. `20,8` worked, but shouldn't have `9,8` also worked for that number?

Comment: then my answer is exactly the case. You are saving something greater than 9 and it gets reduced to the maximum possible value for the field. Try changing your filed to DECIMAL(10,8) and it should save things like that :) increase the first number to save decimals with higher value.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

`DECIMAL (9,8)` means 9 digits **in total** and 8 of that after the decimal point.

So what is the max number of that decimal? it is `9.99999999`. You get that number when the one you sent is bigger than it is possible to store. MySQL just stores as high as possible when the value overflows.